# How do I make my application to run or wait until my "Task" completes?

Tags: c#, task

I have below `c#` code whose responsibility is to fetch the details from `database` and do some actions.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ProcessTask().Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"There was an exception: {ex.ToString()}");
        }
    }
```

Here is the Task

```
    static private async Task ProcessTask()
    {
        //Connect to database
        //fetch data 
        //update data based on condition
    }
```

But my program comes out before completing the task!

One of the methods inside `ProcessTask` is waiting for the "Connected" event,  hence Task assumes that it's completed.

**End Goal**: I want to run this code in windows scheduler. so that every one hour I can check the database and do update. so I can not use "console.readline()"

Comment: Your code seems correct, Calling `.Wait()` will ensure the task is completed before continuing. How did you know it came out before completion?

Comment: I kept a debugger in the end, and application console window closed when it comes out of last line.

Comment: Oh, that just means the application finishes, I'm pretty sure your task is completed. If you want to keep the console window open, add a `Console.ReadLine()` after the `.Wait()` line.

Comment: I have updated question with end goal. please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            await ProcessTask();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"There was an exception: {ex.ToString()}");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like below

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        callMethod();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static async void callMethod()
    {
        Task<int> task = Method1();
        int count = await task;
        Method2(count);
    }
    // Do your db call here
    public static async Task<int> Method1()
    {
        int count = 0;
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Method 1");
                count += 1;
            }
        });
        return count;
    }


    public static void Method2(int count)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Total count is " + count);
    }
```

Comment: I can not use  Console.ReadKey();, because I am deploying it as scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are dong this in a Console app. So I would suggest to make two changes.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        ProcessTask()
           .GetAwaiter()
           .GetResult(); // This will give you a better exception details compared to Task.Wait().
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"There was an exception: {ex.ToString()}");
#if DEBUG
        Console.ReadLine(); // Generic error handler. Stop exiting. So you can read the exception. 
#endif
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I am doing in console app. and once everything works, I want to put EXE inside the windows scheduler so that it can run every one hour. so I can not use "Console.Readline"

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` is for debugging only. You can decorate it with `#if DEBUG` to make sure it's not running in production. Also it's important to add proper logging if you are planning to use this in Production.

Comment: @KosalaW You don't need Console.ReadLine. If you start the program with the debugger it will stop where the exception happened. If you don't want the debugger, start it with Ctrl+F5 and it will keep the console window open at the end.

Comment: @ckuri This is true for unhandled exceptions. In this case OP has a generic exception handler.